# Python IDLE is glitching when I try to load images with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I don't know how to explain this so I have included a video showing you what's happening.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCNl24mpko0&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how it says it's trying to load "imagesed shield.png" This is because the baskslash is escaping "r". Putting an "r" at the front will fix it by converting the string to a raw string, as will replacing the backslash with a forward slash, or escaping the backslash itself.

```
red_shield = pyg.image.load(r'images\red shield.png')
red_shield2 = pyg.image.load('images/red shield.png')
red_shield3 = pyg.image.load('images\\red shield.png')
```

Edit: I suppose I should mention that I assume this is due to IDLE trying to represent a break character (\r is a break character, hence the answer). I don't really know if it's a real issue in the grand scheme of things.